# Trabalhando com Formulário AutoSize

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Tenho um fomulário com a propriedade **AutoSize** = *True*, e dois **GroupBox** um que fica ao meio e outro que fica no rodapé. Existe uma função que torna o GroupBox de baixo invisível caso esteja visível e vice-versa, e como a propriedade AutoSize do Formulário está igual a True o mesmo se auto ajusta e exibe apenas a área em que o GroupBox do meio se encontra caso o GroupBox do rodapé fique invisível(*Visible=False*) e volta a mostrar caso ele volte a ser visível(*Visible=True*).
Até aí tudo OK.
Porém se eu configurar a propriedade do GroupBox que fica no rodapé como **AlBottom** isso não ocorre.
O Formulário inicia com os 2 GroupBox aparecendo, quando altero a propriedade Visible do GroupBox do rodapé para False ele desaparece e o formulário se auto ajusta, porém se eu alterar a propriedade Visible para True **não acontece nada**. O Formulário não se auto ajusta para exibir o GroupBox do rodapé.
Se o AutoSize do fomulário estiver igual a False **tudo ocorre normalmente**.
Existe alguma forma de resolver este problema sem alterar a propriedade AutoSize do formulário para False e sem alterar a propriedade Align do GroupBox do rodapé para AlCustom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça o contrário.

Se você fizer uma pilha de align top, o form vai respeitar a ordem original.

Seguem fontes:
*(para adaptar o dfm, botão direito no form, view as text)*

### DFM:

```delphi
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  AutoSize = True
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 433
  ClientWidth = 635
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object GroupBox1: TGroupBox
    Left = 0
    Top = 41
    Width = 635
    Height = 177
    Align = alTop
    Caption = 'GroupBox1'
    TabOrder = 0
    ExplicitLeft = -8
    ExplicitTop = 8
    object Button1: TButton
      Left = 48
      Top = 48
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Button1'
      TabOrder = 0
      OnClick = Button1Click
    end
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 635
    Height = 41
    Align = alTop
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    TabOrder = 1
    ExplicitLeft = -8
    ExplicitTop = 1
    object Button3: TButton
      Left = 72
      Top = 10
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Button3'
      TabOrder = 0
      OnClick = Button3Click
    end
  end
  object GroupBox2: TGroupBox
    Left = 0
    Top = 218
    Width = 635
    Height = 215
    Align = alTop
    Caption = 'GroupBox2'
    TabOrder = 2
    ExplicitLeft = -8
    ExplicitTop = 256
    object Button2: TButton
      Left = 48
      Top = 48
      Width = 75
      Height = 25
      Caption = 'Button1'
      TabOrder = 0
      OnClick = Button2Click
    end
  end
end
```

### PAS:

```delphi
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    GroupBox1: TGroupBox;
    GroupBox2: TGroupBox;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Button3: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if GroupBox2.Visible then
    GroupBox2.Visible := false
  else
    GroupBox2.Visible := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if GroupBox1.Visible then
    GroupBox1.Visible := false
  else
    GroupBox1.Visible := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if GroupBox2.Visible then
    GroupBox2.Visible := false
  else
    GroupBox2.Visible := true;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Filipe.Fonseca, resolveu mesmo. Estava quebrando a cabeça aqui. Muito simples!